# When I click on tab then images disappear

Tags: html, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application and when I click on a textbox and then I tap on the "tab" key two images on the same popup disappears. Any idea why?

Here is the code for the images that are disappearing.

```
    <a href="#">
    <img id="imgUnlockabc" src="/images/lock.png" title="Unlock Field" class="unlockabc" width="12px" height="16px" />
    </a>

    <img id="imgUnlockabc" src="/images/lock.png" title="Unlock Field" class="unlockabc"  width="12px" height="16px"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Your code isn't enough to identify the problem.

2 - you can't use same id more than one time in same page

3 - try change class name.

```
 <a href="#">
  <img id="imgUnlockabc1" src="/images/lock.png" title="Unlock Field" class="unlockabc1" width="12px" height="16px" />
</a>

<img id="imgUnlockabc2" src="/images/lock.png" title="Unlock Field" class="unlockabc2"  width="12px" height="16px"/>
```